# open detail into table like google inbox

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing an angular app and have used bootstrap tables in my template for list some records. I want show detail of record into table, something similar to how [google inbox](https://inbox.google.com/) does it.
[image: detail into table]

To distance 2 rows, just use padding-bottom

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="edit">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 100px;">Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="detail">I am the div into table></div>
```

But how do I place a div element under the class edit of tr tag  ???

Comment: Using table could restrict you from doing DOM manipulation. You could use div tags to show inbox collapsed records. Once user click on any of the div, you can hide clicked div and add details view at same index.

Comment: Ok, for the idea. But I could not insert a div in each row, without spoiling the graphics. Can you give me an example of html?